# Order Alphabetically and Display By Group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to display a list of titles from my database in alphabetical order and also in blocks.

I want to output the letter and then include all titles that start with that letter. For example:

- A

  - Apple
  - anotherthing
- B

  - Bob

I know that I can order my results using .order('title'), but I'm not sure what the best way to write the display code is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
titles.group_by {|word| word[0].upcase }
```

So, then if:

```
titles = ['Apple', 'anothersomething', 'Bob']
```

Then:

```
grouped_titles = titles.group_by {|word| word[0].upcase }
 => {"A"=>["Apple", "anothersomething"], "B"=>["Bob"]}
```

In order to be certain about the ordering, you can sort the resulting Hash, which converts it into an array:

```
grouped_titles = grouped_titles.sort_by{|k, v| k}
 => [["A", ["Apple", "anothersomething"]], ["B", ["Bob"]]]
```

Then you can iterate over the resulting array.

```
<% grouped_titles.each do |initial_letter, titles| %>
 -display stuff here-
<% end %>
```

Note that this is grouping in Ruby, rather than in the database (which would be done by using a `.group` method on the relation), but if you were already displaying all the data in the page, this method should be fine.

Comment: Thanks. I also have numbers so I added group_by{|word| word.name[0].capitalize.match(/[A-Z]/) ? word.name[0].capitalize : "#" }

Comment: You'll lose the ordering, though, because it's a Hash. I'd use ranges like `("A".."Z")` and `(0..9)` for the iteration part.

Comment: Actually, as of 1.9, Ruby Hashes are ordered (http://www.igvita.com/2009/02/04/ruby-19-internals-ordered-hash/), so if the items are inserted in alphabetical order, they'll stay that way when you iterate. It also means you can sort a Hash, which is probably worth doing.

Comment: That said, I've edited the answer to include sorting the hash, which converts it into an array - the same iteration should still work.

Comment: @MrTheWalrus How would someone do this in Liquid? [Here is my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35707352/how-to-group-data-by-first-letter-from-a-csv-file-in-liquid).

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution proposed by @MrTheWalrus will work, as long as you iterate properly through the list to maintain order, but I'll propose an alternative that will be a bit quicker if your list gets long. First make sure your list is in order as it seems you have done:

```
@titles = Title.order(:title)
```

Then the iteration in the view will look like this:

```
<% cur_letter = nil %>
<% @titles.each do |t| %>
  <% title_letter = t.name[0].capitalize.match(/[A-Z]/) ? t.name[0].capitalize : "#" %> 
  <% if title_letter != cur_letter %>
    <% cur_letter = title_letter %>
    <%= cur_letter %>
  <% end %>
  <%= t.name %>
<% end %>
```

I'll admit it's a bit ugly as view code, but it allows you to iterate once through the list, maintain order, and avoid `group_by` which is not a trivial operation.